# How to import custom Python modules in the dbt python model

Tags: python, dbt

```
pipeline/
    modelling/
        model/
            schema/
                sample_model.py
        some_domain/
            filter_out.py
```

I trying to import filter_out.py model in the dbt model by providing the path

sample_model is **dbt python model**

```
 **filter_out.py**

from test.filter_out import filter_out
```

But not able import it. But it is expecting some `__init__.py`

But dbt is not working properly with `__init__.py`

Any idea what is causing this problem. Let me know if there are any other details that would help.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023-08-02, and as noted by [hc_dev's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76067152/10288333), there are "workarounds" but you can't reuse dbt python models as if they were traditional python files/packages:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/python-models#code-reuse

The documentation suggests to use declare a UDFs instead or to build your logic and build it as if it was a PyPI Package then import it (but it means that you need to make it available in your backend, i.e. Dataproc, Snowflake..., not simply locally).

But we lack a bit of context to clearly answer your question: What are you trying to do? Do you really want to reuse the same logic twice or do you want to simply "use the output of a given model"? I'm asking because if you simply want to access the output, you can simply use ref like this ([as explained in this doc](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/python-models#referencing-other-models)):

```
upstream_model = dbt.ref("upstream_model_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) to import your custom module or package. This is explained in [Software patterns for udf registration](https://blog.devgenius.io/running-dbt-in-production-with-python-udfs-ec28744d619#a6bf).

Similar as [Using PyPI packages](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/python-models#using-pypi-packages) which uses `dbt.config(packages = ["package_name"])` to register those packages, you can also import

> **Private Python packages** — In addition to importing reusable functions from public PyPI packages, many data platforms support uploading custom Python assets and registering them as packages. The upload process looks different across platforms, but your code’s actual import looks the same.